# Read and writing data files using python

Tags: python, function, file-io

I'm trying to write a program that reads 3 class data files such as period1.txt, period2.txt. Inside those files are the first name, last name, and 3 test scores from 3 different students.

The format of the data files looks like this

```
Meagan. Hesse. 99. 99. 99
```

My program is then suppose to take the average assign a grade and write the results and also the students names in another txt folder such as period1cgrade and period2grade

I've tried fixing some of the problems but it looks like it's still a work in progress I'm not to sure whether i'm opening the data files right, can you take a look at that part

```
def calcaverage(test1,test2,test3):   
    for count in range(test1,test2,test3):
        curraverage=0
        curraverage=((test1[count]+ test2[count]+ test3[count])/3)
        currentaverage.append(curraverage)
        if curraverage>= 90:
            grade= "A"
            lettergrades.append(grade)
        elif curraverage >= 80 and curraverage < 90:
            grade= "B"
            lettergrades.append(grade)
        elif curraverage >= 70 and curraverage < 80:
            grade= "C"
            lettergrades.append(grade)
        elif curraverage < 70:
            grade= "F"
            lettergrades.append(grade)

name=[]
test1=[]
test2=[]
test3=[]
averagescore=[]
lettergrades=[]



with open ("period1.txt", 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        values = line.split()
        name.append(values[0] + ','+ values[1])
        for line in infile:
            values = line.split()
            score1=float(values[2])
            test1.append(score1)
            for line in infile:
                values = line.split()
                score2=float(values[3])
                test2.append(score2)
                for line in inline:
                    values = line.split()
                    score3=float(values[4])
                    test3.append(score3)
averagescore=calcaverage(test1,test2,test3)

print(line)
```

Comment: So exactly HOW is this code not working?

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your code. Personally I prefer attaching a debugger, stepping through the code a line at a time and inspecting variables to see what is going on. Other prefer using `print()` and similar methods to display the variables as the code progresses. Without more information, we won't be able to help you much. At a minimum, we need to know any errors, what output you get, etc... It would also be helpful to know eg how many lines are read from the file, whether or not the loops are running the right number of times, etc

Comment: You should not iterate over the same object (use it in a for loop) multiple times like you are doing above.  "for line in infile" is being called multiple times.  TBH, I've never done this and am not sure exactly what it does behind the scenes.  My guess is this represents the three input files, or is supposed to.

Comment: For starters, you've got three nested `for line in infile:` statements which can't be right. There should only be one since you can only read the file once per `open()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Someone already submitted an answer but this is, in my opinion, the cleanest way to do what you want...

```
marks = {90:'A', 80:'B', 70:'C', 0:'F'}
grades = {}

def calc_grades(infile):
    with open(infile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.read().splitlines():
            fname, lname, g1, g2, g3 = line.split('. ')
            avg = sum(map(float, [g1, g2, g3]))/3
            name = "%s %s" % (fname, lname)
            grades[name] = marks[min(marks.keys(), key=lambda k: abs(k-avg) if avg>=k else 100)]

def put_grades(outfile):
    with open(outfile, 'w+') as f:
        f.writelines(["%s: %s\n" % (k, v) for k, v in grades.items()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    calc_grades('period1.txt')
    put_grades('p1_grades.txt')
```

**Edit:** Fixed lambda expression

Answer (score 0):

Here's how **I** would do it:

```
FILENAMES = [("period1.txt", "period1grade.txt"), ... ]

for inpath, outpath in FILENAMES:
    with open(inpath) as infile, open(outpath, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            if line:
                first, last, grades* = map(str.strip,line.split('.'))
                grades = map(int, grades) # maybe float?
                output = "{}. {}. {}\n".format(first, last, sum(grades)/len(grades)
                outfile.write(output)
```

I see now that you have to assign a letter grade, so I would do exactly as you did and write a separate function for that

```
def getlettergrade(grades):
    """Returns a letter grade ["A","B","C","F"] given a list of ints as grades of 100"""
    percent = sum(grades)/len(grades)
    if grade >= 90: return "A"
    elif grade >= 80: return "B"
    elif grade >= 70: return "C"
    else: return "F"
```